# Deleting an item off of Windows Forms in both the Code.cs and Code.cs[design] properly

Tags: c#, winforms

When I'm making a Windows form application, and I use the toolbox and drag an item onto the form, I get a nice tool on the form, like button, listbox, etc.  When I double click on the button, listBox, etc it goes to the text code part where all the delegates are.  Also known as the event handlers.  But what happens when I want to delete an item on the visual part of the application (the Code.cs[design] part)?  I select it, then right click it and then delete it.  It's off the screen.  But, the problem is with all the event handlers.  They're still left in the text-based code section but I don't need them there at all, and they generate a whole bunch of errors because references are gone, etc.

So, basically, I'm asking someone on the forum how to completely get rid of a button, listBox, both the visual part of it in code.cs[design] and in the code.cs part?  I don't want to go line-by-line in deleting junk, I want to get rid of the button/listBox and it's accompanying code in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 3):

It will delete such an automatically added event handler.  But only if you didn't modify it and left it untouched with no code added.  Visual Studio will **not** delete code that you have written.  The reason for that should be obvious.

If this happens a lot then you need to get a pair of scissors and cut the mouse umbilical cord.  Design first, program later.

Answer (score 2):

I can't be done and it shouldn't.

You **first** delete the visible control and **after that** you delete the code stubs.

The handler assignments in the `Designer.cs` are then being deleted with the visible control automagically, as they were created.

Just make sure to get the order right: **first** delete the controls **then** the code.

Unless you mix those up there is no need to ever edit the `designer.cs` file. The code may contain important stuff **you** wrote. Therefore is is not deleted by studio.

You create it,  you delete it! Two steps, period.

PS: The code stubs are (unfortunately) added chronologically. It would be nice if they were grouped by the controls they belong to. If you are in doubt, you can always use the 'find all references' command to find those methods buried in the past..

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe there's a way to alphabetically sort the event-handlers?  That would put them in the right order because the way they are auto generated is always, control_whateverAction.

Comment: you are right and that may well be so. There are many `add-ins` for VS but I was always reluctant to install them. __Anybody knows a recommended one?__

Answer (score 1):

If you have a code stub generated, delete the method. Once that's done, Click on your 'forms view' - you will have an error screen shown.

Click on the link, and it will being you to the designer view, with your cursor shown on a specific line. Delete this line of code. Having that done, you could then delete the physical element from your designer.

Comment: Yes that works. But it really is the recipe of repairing after breaking things. Do it right in the first place and you won't need to repair the broken links..

Comment: @TaW: I know prevention is better than cure, but sometimes mistakes happen (i.e. double clicking on controls), so are hence unavoidable. I understand saying 'dont do it in the first place' is technically correct, I still feel it isn't exactly 'a perfect answer' when this sort of damage is already done.

Comment: Yes and __sometimes I actually do it on purpose__: when I'm not sure which event to use, which has which parameters, I often add both and check in the stub. Then I delete the stub(s), F7, click on the error link and delete the line(s). so yes a helpful answer in its own right!